# how to run wordpress php snippet mysql update command from ssh and/ultimately cron

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to run an SQL update command script stored in a wordpress plugin PHP Snippet using a secure shell to test it, with the intention of calling the same command from a cron job using tsohost.

**PHP snippet below**

```
global $wpdb;    
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;

$result = $wpdb->get_results("
INSERT INTO dm_cash_accounts_transactions (name, amount, type, cash_account_id, user_id) 
SELECT 
name, 
quantity * amount, 
type_id,
account_id,
user_id 
FROM 
dm_scheduledd
WHERE 
paydate = DATE(NOW())
AND
dm_scheduledd.user_id = '".$user_id."'
AND
updated = 'n'
");


print_r($result);
```

I can run the above snippet from a webpage using a shortcode

```
[wbcr_php_snippet id="14984" title="Update Cash Accounts Transactions"]
```

I am struggling to run the above script using secure shell. I have tried a number of options

```
bash-3.2$ wget -O /dev/null --no-check-certificate https://dividendmanager.co.uk/update-cash-accounts-transactions
```

The above command appears to run ok, but does not update the database table. I think I need a command to login to the database and call the PHP snippet, any suggestions appreciated. Thanks Colin

Answer (score 2):

If that was a php a stand alone php file, you should load wp global bootstrap class, please include wp-load.php in beginning of the file;

I don't think that `$current_user` can be retrieved by the bash too, this is related to user session

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I am testing your proposal but I need to go out, will pick it up later tonight or tomorrow, I assume the including the wp-load.php should pick up the mysql database name and login details to allow mysql to execute ? thanks Colin

Comment: including `wp-load.php` will allow you to access WordPress functions and global variables - which will allow the SQL to process - just note that as @eye tag's said - there will be no user though. (Side note, you should be using [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_get_current_user) instead.) This is because there won't be a logged in user, so the `$current_user` will be set to `0`.

Comment: I have added the an include wp-config.php to my PHP file holding the database access and this has resolved my problems, many thanks to all Colin